# recreate a .js file for multiply purposes

Tags: javascript

I Have a .js with multiply elements inside and functions and i use it with the 'document.write' in the index.js. I want this file to reuse it as 'new .js;' as many time i need it. Is there any way to do it?
Example:

```
var renderer = document.createElement('div');
var bG = document.createElement('div');
var icon = document.createElement('img');
var lock = document.createElement('img');
var delete = document.createElement('button');
var txt = document.createElement('p');
var users = document.createElement('button');
var rIcon = document.createElement('img');

(function () {
    renderer.id = 'Renderer';
    bG.id = 'BG';
    icon.id = 'icon';
    lock.id = 'Lock';
    delete.id = 'Delete';
    txt.id = 'txt';
    users.id = 'Users';
    rIcon.id = 'rIcon';

    renderer.appendChild(bG),
    renderer.appendChild(users), renderer.appendChild(txt), renderer.appendChild(lock),
    renderer.appendChild(delete), renderer.appendChild(icon),renderer.appendChild(rIcon);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer);

    users.addEventListener('click', OnPress);
    users.addEventListener('mouseover', OnrollOver);
    users.addEventListener('mouseout', OnrollOut);
    delete.addEventListener('click', DeleteClick);

}());
```

I am trying with no hope... Do i need to make it class with constructor but if i make it, and how i will make it, how i will use it with the 'document.write' cause i need it and before the recreation?

Regards.

Comment: Where are you using `document.write`? Why do you "need it"? Multiple elements may not share the same id.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can tell you about, that you must keep away from the language keywords while naming your variables and function, like the `delete` variable you created.

The second thing, you can do that:

```
function createRenderer() {
    let old = document.getElementsByClassName('Renderer')

    let renderer = document.createElement('div');
    let bG = document.createElement('div');
    let icon = document.createElement('img');
    let lock = document.createElement('img');
    let deleteBu = document.createElement('button');
    let txt = document.createElement('p');
    let users = document.createElement('button');
    let rIcon = document.createElement('img');

    renderer.classList.add('Renderer')
    renderer.id = 'Renderer' + old.length + 1;
    bG.id = 'BG' + old.length + 1;
    icon.id = 'icon' + old.length + 1;
    lock.id = 'Lock' + old.length + 1;
    deleteBu.id = 'Delete' + old.length + 1;
    txt.id = 'txt' + old.length + 1;
    users.id = 'Users' + old.length + 1;
    rIcon.id = 'rIcon' + old.length + 1;

    renderer.append( bG, icon, lock, deleteBu, txt, users, rIcon )

    users.addEventListener('click', OnPress);
    users.addEventListener('mouseover', OnrollOver);
    users.addEventListener('mouseout', OnrollOut);
    deleteBu.addEventListener('click', DeleteClick);

    return renderer
}
```

and now your function is just a template for your renderer div, you can call it as much as you want, and every time you have an entirely new created renderer.

then you can use this function in many many places and you can assign it to a new variable too, and these how to use the function:

```
document.body.append( createRenderer() ) // to append the renderer to the body

document.body.appendChild( createRenderer() )  // the same the above

anotherElement.append( createRenderer() )   // to add the renderer to another div
```

and you can assign a new renderer in a new variable and use it as you can:

```
let newRendererOne = createRenderer()
newRendererOne.append( someChildren )   // to append new children for that specific renderer

let newRendererTwo = createRenderer()
newRendererTwo.style.color = "red"   // to change the bg color for that specific render.
```

and you can create many of it inside a loop.

I hope the idea is clear now..

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Is there any way to get the txt.id or any other element id without a loop in the children element after this: anotherElement.append( createRenderer() ) <-- Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, I think you're asking for how to get the id of the elements your `createRenderer` will create to you, but the `id`s are just as you out them with a small append of the number of the renderer in the page..
And there is another great way, which you can receive a special `id` key inside the `createRenderer ` function to create the new renderer with the specified `id` every time.

Please let me know, If I understood your comment in a wrong way, and explain me what exactly you mean.

Comment: I mean if i create the renderer with : let newRender = createRenderer(); and the i want to append it in another element like anotherElement.appendChild(newRender). If i want to do: anotherElement.getElementById('txt12') he throws an error that the getElementById is not a function but if i loop inside the anotherElement.children.length i can find it, so my question was if is there an easier way to get an element id without loop through the anotherElement, like anotherElement.getElementById('txt12') where id: txt12 is the id of the one txt was created by the createRenderer();  Thank you.

Comment: I got it, ok..
That's correct, there is nothing called `anotherElement.getElementById("txt12")` or `anyElement.getElementById()` because if you want to get an element with its id you just need to say `document.getElementById("txt12")` and this will get you the element you want.

Comment: Note that the `getElementById()` method is a method for the `document` object, not in any dom object.